# use cppcheck without defining all the macros

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I use cppcheck on a project using the boost library. The headers in this library contain a huge amount of macro that I don't even use in my sources. Nevertheless, cppcheck explore paths depending on these macros that I think useless. Is there a way to tell cppcheck to ignore all macros unless it's defined in a source code using a #define?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but you can specify `define` to cppcheck so it evaluates only one branch:

see `-D`/`-U` options.

Comment: so if I have 10 macros, and if I define 3 of them (when compiling or in my source), do I need to undef the 7 others?

Comment: @Brahim: if you have something like `#ifdef UNSET_MACRO1`, yes to avoid to check both paths.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the the necessary part from cppcheck documentation:

```
-D<ID>               Define preprocessor symbol. Unless --max-configs or
                     --force is used, Cppcheck will only check the given
                     configuration when -D is used.
                     Example: '-DDEBUG=1 -D__cplusplus'.
-U<ID>               Undefine preprocessor symbol. Use -U to explicitly
                     hide certain #ifdef <ID> code paths from checking.
                     Example: '-UDEBUG'
```

You are able to define (-D) or undefine (-U) custom preprocesser symbols with these options.

Another option that is potentially interesting is

```
-f, --force          Force checking of all configurations in files. If used
                     together with '--max-configs=', the last option is the
                     one that is effective.
```

and

```
--max-configs=<limit>
                     Maximum number of configurations to check in a file
                     before skipping it. Default is '12'. If used together
                     with '--force', the last option is the one that is
                     effective.
```

This means the following:

```
cppcheck --force <PATH_TO_YOUR_CODE>
```

Cppcheck verifies all combinations of preprocessor paths, which could lead to long checking times on large code bases.

The corresponding documentation can be found [here](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.html#idp4643616).

Answer (score 3):

One option is to ignore lines with missing macros by putting this comment above the offending line:

```
// cppcheck-suppress unknownMacro
```

Answer (score 0):

Use --config-exclude= to exclude the directories that contain unmanageable configurations. It only excludes header files.